# Как проверить, требует ли папка прав root в языке C (Язык C, UNIX)?

Tags: c, файлы, unix, ос, root

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить в языкe С, требует ли папка права root?

Сравниваю переменную типа mode_t с флагами (маркерами) разрешений (S_IWUSR и так далее), но среди данных маркеров нету ничего на проверку root.
Проверка на обычную папку if((bits & S_IFREG)==0) тоже ничего не даёт, потому что определяет своё значение как раз по тому, имеется ли право доступа read.

На всякий случай привожу код, извиняюсь за польский, он, думаю, здесь не критичен.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void listuj(char* dirName);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(argc==2)
        listuj(argv[1]);
    else 
        printf ("Niepoprawna liczba argumentow, podaj jeden.\n");
    return 0;
}

void listuj(char* dirName){
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *theDir;
    
    struct stat st;
    if(stat(dirName, &st) == 0){
    printf("Katalog %s istnieje\n",dirName);
    mode_t bits = st.st_mode;
    if((bits & S_IRUSR)==0){
        printf("Wlasciciel nie ma uprawnienia Read \n");
    } 
    else {
        printf("Wlasciciel ma uprawnienie Read \n");
    }
        if((bits & S_IWUSR)==0){
            printf("Wlasciciel nie ma uprawnienia Write \n");
        } 
        else {
            printf("Wlasciciel ma uprawnienie Write \n");
        }
            if((bits & S_IXUSR)==0){
                printf("Wlasciciel nie ma uprawnienia Execute \n");
            } 
            else {
                printf("Wlasciciel ma uprawnienie Execute \n");
            }
        
        if (chdir(dirName) != 0){
            
            if((bits & S_IFREG)==0){
            printf ("Nie mam dostepu! \n");
                if((bits & S_IRUSR)==0){
                printf("Nie ma uprawnienia Read! \n");
                }
                else {
                printf ("Wymaga praw root! \n");
                }
            }
    
        }
        else{
        theDir=opendir("./");
        int regulars=0;
        while(entry=readdir(theDir))
            switch(entry->d_type){
                case DT_REG: regulars++; break;
                default: 
                break;
            }
        printf("liczba plikow zwyklych (-) %d\n", regulars);
        
        closedir(theDir);   
        }       
}
        else {
        printf("Katalog %s nie istnieje\n",dirName);
        exit(1);    
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿А где вы раздобываете такие примеры на польском?

Comment: Это уже моя программа, основанная на примере нашего преподавателя. Я, правда, стараюсь черпать немного глубже. Если интересно, где учусь, то WAT, Варшава. А почему спрашиваете?

Comment: Права - это тонкая вещь. Почитайте про команды в консоли `getfacl`, `setfacl`. Они задают индивидуальный контроль доступа.

Comment: Почитаю, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На прямую опеределить не получится.

Среди полей mode_t структуры stat нет ничего на проверку root. Но в этой же структуре есть поля:

```
uid_t st_uid
gid_t st_gid
```

которые показывают владельца и группу.
Сравнивая владельца и группу, а так же права доступа для остальных можно определить может ли не root получить доступ к файлу (каталог это тоже файл).

Comment: UCL да... В принципе косвенно может подтвердить требования рута, но это совершенно не факт...

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите на [access](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html).

Можете поиграться с

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  errno = 0;
  int rc = access(av[1] ? av[1] : "/", R_OK | W_OK | X_OK);
  printf ("%m rc = %d\n", rc);
  
  return rc;
}
```

Comment: ¿И чем тут полезен `access`? Его результат в общем случае никак не зависит от того, нужны ли права root или нет.

Comment: Не понятно зачем минусовать верный ответ, действительно access возвращает флаги чтения/записи/запуска файла/папки/процесса. По ним можно понять есть-ли у пользователя доступ к файлу/папке/процессу или нет.

Comment: access всегда проверяет права доступа основываясь на real user  ID процесса. И имеет смысл к использованию в suid процессах, остальные процессы будут использовать EID. Не говоря о том что она не даст ответа на вопрос доступ есть только у root для процесса у которого RID не 0

Comment: @EugeneX А по тому, есть ли у пользователя доступ к файлу/папке/процессу или нет, нельзя понять, нужны ли для доступа к ней права root или нет.

Comment: @user7860670 Хой! Да ты открыл новый способ получить permission list в nix like системах! Ну ок... Поясни мне тогда что такое root права в целом. Кроме как прямой проверки на запись, или проверкой UCL файла ты никак не сможешь отличить рута не от рута. Изучи хотя-бы сначала как работает root user... Ну или дай свой гениальный пример в студию.. Я тоже хочу посмотреть...

Comment: @user7860670, в общем случае вы правы. Однако, в простейшем инсталляторе (к примеру) такой вызов позволит ответить на вопрс *надо ли делать su root для действий по установке?*. Понятно, все зависит от задачи, текущей политике на данной системе и т.п.

Comment: Определить sudo кстати достаточно просто, `getuid() < 1` всё что ниже 1, это пользователь с правами, определить конкретно что за пользователь и есть-ли у него определённый permission в общих чертах нельзя, только отдельно проверять нужную папку/файл/процесс в конце концов есть в системе вещи к которым даже sudoers и root права не имеют...

Comment: Кажется дискуссия заходит в тупик. В исходных данных нет указания ни с какими правами запускается программа, ни как запускается (sudo или нет). Просто общий случай, любой пользователь запускает и смотрит только root или нет имеет права.